# python pygame.camera.init() NO vidcapture

Tags: python, camera, usb, pygame, webcam

I am trying to initialize the camera module in pygame and display video from a usb webcam. This is my code:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.camera import *
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
cam.start()
image = cam.get_image()
```

Yet i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Freddie/Desktop/CAMERA/Test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    pygame.camera.init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\camera.py", line 67, in init
    _camera_vidcapture.init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\_camera_vidcapture.py", line 21, in init
    import vidcap as vc
ImportError: No module named vidcap
```

PLS HELP!!! Im on Windows

Comment: ... and what should we say? The error is clear: it cannot find the module `vidcap`. Did you install it? How did you install it? without these information how are we supposed to tell you what's wrong with the installation?

Comment: From the pygame.camera docs: `Pygame currently supports only Linux and v4l2 cameras.`  http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html   It's possible that the documentation is outdated, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I met the same problem.
The error info of "ImportError: No module named vidcap" indicates that python interpreter didn't find  the vidcap module on you machine.

so you'd better follow these steps.

1. Download the vidcap from http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/

2.Then copy the corresponding version of dll (which named "vidcap.pyd" in VideoCapture-0.9-5\VideoCapture-0.9-5\Python27\DLLs) to "your python path"\DLLs\ .

3.restart you script.

Done!.

Answer (score 3):

The camera module can only be used on linux

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem but I found out that its not included on windows ONLY LINUX

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pygame

import pygame.camera

import time, string


from VideoCapture import Device

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.camera.init()

cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480),"RGB")

cam.start()

img = pygame.Surface((640,480))

cam.get_image(img)

pygame.image.save(img, "img2.jpg")

cam.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`pygame.camera`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html) is only supported on linux:

> Pygame currently supports only Linux and v4l2 cameras.

An alternative solution is to use the [OpenCV `VideoCapture`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html). Install OpenCV for Python (*cv2*) (see [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)).

Opens a camera for video capturing:

```py
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Grabs a camera frame:

```py
success, camera_image = capture.read()
```

Convert the camera frame to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object using [`pygame.image.frombuffer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer):

```py
camera_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(
              camera_image.tobytes(), camera_image.shape[1::-1], "BGR")
```

See also [Camera and Video](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_camera_and_video.md#camera-and-video)

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
success, camera_image = capture.read()

window = pygame.display.set_mode(camera_image.shape[1::-1])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = success
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    success, camera_image = capture.read()
    if success:
        camera_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(
            camera_image.tobytes(), camera_image.shape[1::-1], "BGR")
    else:
        run = False
    window.blit(camera_surf, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```