# How to fix 'No module named vidcap' in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have camera set up, which works fine. The thing is, there is an ModuleNotFoundError when I am trying to import pygame.
(Note:I am using windows)

This is a test project, and I have to make a camera out of pygame. I've tried some youtube tutorials and I messed with pygame but it always causes an Error.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pygame.camera
pygame.camera.init()
camera = pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0]
pyg = pygame.camera.Camera(camera (640, 480), 'HSV')
--snip--
    if pyg.query_image():
        win.blit(pyg.get_image(surface=win), (0, 0))
pygame.quit()
```

I resulted in the same error every time I tried.
The Error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\_camera_vidcapture.py", line 31, in init
    import vidcap as vc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vidcap'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\roche\Documents\pygame_camera.py", line 5, in <module>
    pygame.camera.init()
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\camera.py", line 68, in init
    _camera_vidcapture.init()
  File "C:\Users\roche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\_camera_vidcapture.py", line 33, in init
    from VideoCapture import vidcap as vc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'VideoCapture'
```

Any Advice?

Comment: Hello, please let us see the full error - ModuleNotFoundError suggests that you don't have something installed.

Comment: Is this the minimal working example? In other words, is this the absolute minimum amount of code that results in the same error? If not, please remove the extraneous code.

Comment: EDIT: I added the error message and deleted some code

Comment: bounty or answer anyone???

Comment: are you using linux?

Comment: Can you add some more info? Which Python version? OS (looks like Windows)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are using Windows. So you need to install `VideoCapture` module for the `pygame.camera`. An easy way is to grab the prebuilt wheel package from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#videocapture) (based on your Python version) and install it with `pip`:

```
pip install VideoCapture‑0.9.5‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl
```

This should fix the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Here the "cp" in "cp37" stands for cpython, the default case, pp would be pypy. The "37" would be python3.7 If you have "Python39" in "C:" then you want "cp39".

Answer (score 3):

[From the pygame documentaion](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html)

```
Pygame currently supports only Linux and v4l2 cameras.

EXPERIMENTAL!: This API may change or disappear in later pygame releases. If you use this, your code will very likely break with the next pygame release.
```

Are you on a windows machine?

You might want to check this previous answer about pygame on windows - [python pygame.camera.init() NO vidcapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266244/python-pygame-camera-init-no-vidcapture)

Comment: Yes, I'm on windows.

Comment: Did you try the solutions in the linked answer?

Comment: I did, but I want a specific version.

Comment: Which specific version are you looking for?

Comment: The newest version

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/download.shtml the version 1.9 seems to be available for Windows? Did you try this one