# Python equivalent of MATLAB's webcamlist command

Tags: python

Is there a python equivalent of MATLAB's webcamlist command, which lists the webcams installed on the PC?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to list all the available camera you can use `pygame`'s [`pygame.camera.list_cameras()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html#pygame.camera.list_cameras)

```
import pygame.camera

pygame.camera.init()

cam_list = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

print(cam_list)
```

P.S For installing `pygame`'s camera, you need to have `VideoCapture` module installed you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56851629/how-to-fix-no-module-named-vidcap-in-python-3-7/57337992#57337992) answer to install it.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work."ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'VideoCapture' " It needs another module that's not available using pip

Comment: Thanks. the pip install method didn't work and it seems to be a Linux only solution from the other thread.

Comment: On Linux, I think `pip install videocapture` would be enough. If you still have a problem it is better to post it as a new question as it is not related to the current question.