# Adding to Python Path DLLs

Tags: python, dll, pygame

I am currently trying to use the camera module from Pygame, a set of Python modules designed for writing video games. Trying to initialize the camera gives the error

> from VideoCapture import vidcap as vc 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'VideoCapture'

I am trying to resolve this error using the instructions from [python pygame.camera.init() NO vidcapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266244/python-pygame-camera-init-no-vidcapture), but I am not sure how to execute step 2 in the recommended solution, which says to add the corresponding version of dll from a downloaded program to "your python path"\DLLs. I understand this is a reference to the python system path, but am not sure what it means to add the dll.

Answer (score 1):

`"your python path"` is the path of your python installation. `DLLs` is the directory `DLLs` under that very path.

So if your python installation is at (e.g.)

```
C:\Users\max.power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
```

then the `"your python path"\DLLs` directory refers to

```
C:\Users\max.power\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs
```

Also note that the `camera` module is marked as experimental, only works with v4l2 cameras and only supports linux out of the box, so I don't know if the answer you linked works at all.