# blit opencv camera capture with pygame throws TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, pygame, webcam, blit

I'm new to pygame and never used it before and wanted to know how I can blit or display my webcam into the surface by using pygame and opencv but I keep getting the message:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<filename>.py", line 51, in <module>      
>    mainWindow()
>  File "<filename>.py", line 43, in mainWindow    
>    draw_window()
>  File "<filename>.py", line 24, in draw_window   
>    WINDOW.blit(camera)
> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not cv2.VideoCapture
> ```

```py
import pygame 
import cv2

pygame.init()

# setting the width and height of the window
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 720
WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("name me")

# background color 
color = (0, 0, 0)

# 0 is the built in webcam
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 700)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 900)

def draw_window():
    # background color 
    WINDOW.fill((color))

    # display object onto the surface (screen)
    WINDOW.blit(camera)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.update()


FPS = 30
def mainWindow():
    # keeping the window open 
    run = True 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while run: 
        # capping it at the set frame rate 
        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        draw_window()


    # closing the window 
    pygame.quit()


# main #
mainWindow()
```

Comment: Please mention which line throws the error. Better yet, paste the whole stack trace that includes the line number.

Comment: did you think you could blit the entire VideoCapture object? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `blit` a `pygame.Surface`. Therefore you have to get frame by frame from the camera and convert it to a `pygame.Surface` object.

Grab a camera frame:

```py
success, camera_image = capture.read()
```

Convert the camera frame to a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object using [`pygame.image.frombuffer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.frombuffer):

```py
camera_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(
              camera_image.tobytes(), camera_image.shape[1::-1], "BGR")
```

Do that in the function `draw_window`:

```py
def draw_window():
    # background color 
    WINDOW.fill((color))
    
    # display object onto the surface (screen)
    success, camera_image = camera.read()
    if success:
          camera_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(camera_image.tobytes(), camera_image.shape[1::-1], "BGR")
          WINDOW.blit(camera_surf, (0, 0))
    
    # update the display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Also see [python pygame.camera.init() NO vidcapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266244/python-pygame-camera-init-no-vidcapture/69053911#69053911) and [PyGameExamplesAndAnswers - Camera and Video](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_camera_and_video.md)

---

Alternative but minimal example:

```py
import pygame
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
success, camera_image = capture.read()

window = pygame.display.set_mode(camera_image.shape[1::-1])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = success
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    success, camera_image = capture.read()
    if success:
        camera_surf = pygame.image.frombuffer(
            camera_image.tobytes(), camera_image.shape[1::-1], "BGR")
    else:
        run = False
    window.blit(camera_surf, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get webcam input into pygame, you could use [pygame.camera](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html)

It supports Windows and Linux webcams natively, falls back to an OpenCV backend on MacOS.

```py
import pygame
import pygame.camera

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720,500))

cam_list = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
camera = pygame.camera.Camera(cam_list[0], (720,500))
camera.start()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill("black")
    screen.blit(camera.get_image(), (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```